# Is my evaluation of this integral correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

We have $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ the ellipsoid described as

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2}+\dots+\frac{x_n^2}{a_n^2} = 1.
\end{equation*}

Through any $x \in E$ we construct the plane tangent to $H$ at $x$ and let $D(x)$ be the distance from this plane to the origin. $D(x)$ is given by

\begin{equation*}
  D(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2}{a_1^4}+\dots+\frac{x_n^2}{a_n^4}}}.
\end{equation*}

Calculate the integral

\begin{equation*}
  I = \int_E D \, d\mathrm{vol}_{n-1}.
\end{equation*}

My progress. We know $d\mathrm{vol}_{n-1} = \frac{\|\nabla g\|}{\left|\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}\right|} \, dx_1\dots dx_{n-1}$ where $g(x) = 0$ defines a hypermanifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$

\begin{align*}
  g(x) &= \frac{x_1^2}{a_1^2}+\dots+\frac{x_n^2}{a_n^2}-1,\\
  \nabla g &= 2 \left(\frac{x_1}{a_1^2},\frac{x_2}{a_2^2},\dots,\frac{x_n}{a_n^2}\right),\\
  \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n} &= 2\frac{x_n}{a_n^2}.
\end{align*}

We notice that

\begin{equation*}
  D(x) = \frac{2}{\|\nabla g\|}.
\end{equation*}

I'm not sure of where to go from here.